# Libre Office Display more visible icons on dark-breeze Kde theme

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, icons, themes, libreoffice

On Kubuntu 16.04 I use the `dark-breeze` theme, but that results into having non-visible icons on libreoffice as the image shows bellow:
[image: libre office on kde with dark-breeze desktop theme]
I like `dark-breeze` desktop theme but I do not like that I am unable to see the icons on Libre Office.

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: There are other icon sets available. Click on `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View > Icon Style` and see if you like something there.

Comment: Ok that solved it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @DK Bose stated select: `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View > Icon Style` Then select the icon theme as the image shows bellow:
[image: Change icon in Libre Office]

For those that the user interface / system language is in Greek should select `Εργαλεία > Επιλογές > Προβολή` and then **maximize** or **enlarge** the window (the options not shown correctly for some reason in the norma sized window) and then select the options as shows the image bellow:

[image: Select Icon theme in libre office]

The `Oxygen` icon theme gave me colorfull icons that I can see them even on a dark theme.

Also in case that you use **neither** Greek nor English as system's language then you can launch the libreoffice in `English` by typing at the terminal:

```
LANG=C libreoffice --writer
```

Then follow the steps mentioned for `English` environment.